# Understanding A/A = I in Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a solution here that I don't quite understand.

Q: Show that if a square matrix A satisfies the equation $A^2+2A+I=0$, then $A$ must be invertible.

$A^2+2A=-I$

$-A^2-2A=I$

I got this far on my own, but the next step confuses me...

$A(-A-2I)=I$

I get that if $A^{-1}=(-A-2I)$ then $A*A^{-1}=I$, however what I'm confused about is when they draw out the $A$ from $-2A$.

Could someone help me understand why $A/A=I$?

Thank you!

Comment: Can't figure out how to get A^(-1) in Latex, I'm super new. If someone can fix it so I can see how it's done that would be great ;)

Comment: @ What is $A/A$?

Comment: 1? I know that an identity matrix has 1's in a diagonal, does that make it a 1 as well?

Comment: @JeffreyDilley It's not that $A/A=I\,$ (which doesn't even make sense), it's that $A * I = A\,$, so that $\,A(A+2I)=A*A + 2 A*I = A^2+2A\,$.

Comment: @dxiv, So if I have some binomial $A^2-2A$ and I want to factor out an $A$(which is the same as dividing all the terms by that number, correct?), the $A^2$ becomes simply $A$ and the $-2A$ becomes $-2I$. Doesn't that mean that $A/A=I?$

Comment: I just read your new comment, that helps clear it up. Thank you!

Comment: @JeffreyDilley To elaborate some more, the only way $A/A$ could make any sense would be to read it as $A * A^{-1}$ (btw, that would be an abuse of notation which is never used, so stay away from it). But that *assumes* that $A^{-1}$ exists i.e. that $A$ has an inverse, which in this case you do not know, yet. In contrast, $A * I=A$ holds true for all matrices $A\,$, regardless of whether they are invertible or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing more than noting that 
$$
-2A=A(-2I)
$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Other note, it is not $A^{-1}=(-A-2I)$ *then* $A*A^{-1}=I$, it is $A*(-A-2I)=I$ and *thus* $(-A-2I)$ is the unique identity.

Comment: What's the difference between then and thus so's I don't misuse in the future?

Comment: so vs then is semantics in my opinion. My critique is that you have the direction of implication in this particular proof is incorrect. You are trying to show $A$ has an inverse. You write a product of the form $AB=I$, this then shows that $A$ is invertible with inverse $B$.

Answer (score 0):

$I$ is not the result of dividing $A$ by $A$ (an operation that is not in general defined); it is the unique matrix that when multiplied by $A$, yields $A$ itself.  Its uniqueness is guaranteed by the group structure of square matrices.  That's what allows us to factor $-A^2-2A$ as $A(-A-2I)$.

That is also true of the scalar $1$, of course.  But you can't subtract a scalar from a matrix.